# Annotation for validating length of elements in the list

Tags: java, validation

In `application.yml` I had key, value pair:

`key: value`
for which I used simple annotation to ensure that it is not null and has minimum length

```
   @NotNull
   @Length(min = 10)
```

but then I transformed it into a list:

```
list:
  - element1
  - element2
  - element3
```

where I can use following annotation:

```
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 1)
```

but how can I ensure minimum length of the elements? I use: `javax.validation.constraints`, `org.hibernate.validator.constraints`.

Comment: Don't understand your question actually ? What is not working ?

Comment: @Eklavya I still want to be able to validate length of string like I was before I used list.